# Oracle update statement with error ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle

I only have two simple tables:

```
test1(id, name)
```

and

```
test2(id, name)
```

I would like to update values in test2 based on test1. If values in test2 does not exist, new rows should be inserted.

My query:

```
MERGE INTO test2 trg
    USING (
      select c.id
      from test1 c
    ) src ON (src.id = trg.id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET
        trg.name = src.name
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (id)
      VALUES (src.id);
```

But this query is throwing me error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SRC"."NAME": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

why is this?

Tables:

```
create table test1
(
id number,
name varchar(10)
)

create table test2
(
id number,
name varchar(10)
)

insert into test1(id, name)
select 1, '1' from dual
union all select 2, '2' from dual
union all select 3, '3' from dual
union all select 4, '4' from dual
union all select 5, '5' from dual
union all select 6, '6' from dual
union all select 7, '7' from dual
union all select 8, '8' from dual
union all select 9, '9' from dual
union all select 10, '10' from dual

commit;

insert into test2(id, name)
select 20, '20' from dual
union all select 21, '21' from dual
union all select 22, '22' from dual

commit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO test2 trg
        USING (
          select c.id,c.name
          from test1 c
        ) src ON (src.id = trg.id)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE
          SET
            trg.name = src.name
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (id,name)
          VALUES (src.id,src.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only column you're selecting in the `src` subquery of your MERGE statement is called `ID`. You need to also select the `NAME` column in that subquery:

```
MERGE INTO test2 trg
    USING (
      select c.id, c.name
      from test1 c
    ) src ON (src.id = trg.id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET
        trg.name = src.name
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (id)
      VALUES (src.id);
```